# Display 'a href' with custom name instead of WP taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, TAXONOMY_NAME, ' ', ', ', ''); ?>
```

The above code currently generates the name of the custom category. That's fine most of the time. But in one location, I want to have a custom 'a href' that shows "see more" instead of displaying the name of the category.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use "get_the_terms" and then "get_term_link" instead of "get_the_term_list", which includes the html.

So you could do

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy );
foreach($terms as $term){
  echo "<a href=". get_term_link( $term->term_id, $taxonomy ). ">CUSTOM LABEL</a>"; 
}
```

Doc for get_the_terms -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms
Doc for get_term_link -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link

Comment: There's a discrepancy here: TAXONOMY_NAME and $taxonomy. 
And the code as shown doesn't work. The page quits loading when it gets to this snippet.

Comment: Ah-ha! It appears that "$taxonomy = TAXONOMY_NAME;" needed to be added before your code (before $terms). I think it works now!